# DevExpress CodeRush: multicursor replacement

Tags: replace, cursor, devexpress, coderush

In Sublime Text there's a way to highlight all similar strings by setting a cursor to every one of them, and then you can just type something, and this text will be printed in every highlight area. In rus version it's called "multicursor".

Is there something like that in CodeRush?

I know about "Replace all" function in Visual Studio. But this approach is not as convenient as the approach described earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that you can see in **[Rename](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument1512)** feature of CodeRush.

Documentation:

> When the **Rename** is activated, it turns all references to the selected
>   variable into the [linked identifiers](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CodeRush/CustomDocument3523.aspx).

> **Linked identifiers** are related sections that are kept synchronized. If
>   you change the text within one of them, all others get updated
>   accordingly.
>
> [image: Linked identifiers]

---

There are also the **[Multi-Select](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument10979)** feature which allows you to select separate text blocks by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but this feature does not allows you to edit every highlight area:
[image: Multi-Select]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Seems like these are all the possibilites. In CodeRush 15.2 it's Refactor-Rename. I found a VS extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f301cf82-e80b-4b92-9e5c-ef7985ae6702?SRC=Home